# no visible interface for selector self

Tags: objective-c, debugging

i was a beginner in iOS developing.
i was so confused that i get this error.i can simply solve it by changing "[self maxRank]" to "[PlayingCard maxRank]"
but i don't why this happen.
thanks in advance.

> this is my code

```
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCard
@synthesize suit=_suit;

+ (NSArray *)validSuits
{
    return @[@"♠︎",@"♣︎",@"♥︎",@"♦︎"];

}
+ (NSArray *)validRanks
{
    return @[@"?",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];

}
+ (NSUInteger)maxRank
{
    return [[PlayingCard validRanks] count]-1;
}
- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit?_suit:@"?";
}

- (void)setSuit:(NSString *)suit
{
    if ([[PlayingCard validSuits] containsObject:suit]) {
        _suit=suit;
    }

}
- (void)setRank:(NSUInteger)rank
{
    if (rank<=[self maxRank]) {       // this is where i get my error
        _rank=rank;
    }
}



- (NSString *)contents
{
    NSArray *rankString=[PlayingCard validRanks];
    return [rankString[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];

}



@end
#import "Card.h"

@interface PlayingCard : Card
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic)NSUInteger rank;
+ (NSArray *)validSuits;
@end
```

Comment: What error did you get? What do you expect it should do and what it does instead? Adding the code to the questions is useful in general, but is really *all* your code necessary here? Can you remove some which is not relevant for the error you get, so the question is better readable?

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C there are two different types of methods:

## 1. Class Method - denoted by a `+` before it

Class methods operate on the class itself. Therefore, when you use `self` in a class method, it refers to the class.

## 2. Instance Method - denoted by a `-` before it

Instance methods operate on a specific **instance** of a class that has been allocated. Therefore, when you use `self` in an instance method, it refers to the instance of that class.

Your `setRank:` method is an instance method but `maxRank` is a class method. When you try to call `maxRank` on `self` from `setRank:`, you are trying to call an instance method named `maxRank`, which does not exist. If you want to call a class method without specifying the class explicitly, you can use the `class` property on all instances:

```
- (void)instanceMethod {
    [self.class maxRank];
}
```

Comment: So,i can use `self` to call the class method in a class method(just like what i do in `maxRank:`),but i can't do this in a instance method.Is that all right.And thanks a lot:)

Comment: @user3843314 that is correct, in a class method, you can use 'self' to call other class methods

Answer (score 0):

The maxRank method is a class method, not an instance method, so you cannot use "self" with it. If you want maxRank to be a instance method, you need to change the leading + sign to a hyphen (-).

Comment: You can use `self` in a class method, it just refers to something different (the class itself instead of an instance)

Answer (score 0):

It's because methods with `+` prefix are class methods, not instance method.

You need to read up on the difference between those.